# Need an alternate way in creation of multiple nodes in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I have 15 hosts and 20 users. Need to create a node with the combination of each host with 20 users. So EOD I should create 15(hosts)*20(Users)=**300**(Nodes).

For me creating these many nodes and managing them is a very hectic job. Do we have any alternate way to run the jobs with the above combinations.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: Hopefully you only have to do that once, but it should be [scripted](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218154667-create-agent-node-from-groovy). Worst case you can replicate on the cmd line, a shell script and reload config feom disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can write down some code to manage the Node and increase or decrease with the code as per need.

For example here is Ansible role : https://github.com/lean-delivery/ansible-role-jenkins-slave

You can use this to add a node and it will join to the master of Jenkin.